# ASP.NET MVC 3. Relative paths don't work for static content. Url.Content is applied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I created a nested web application on IIS in Default Web Site (:80 port). Its virtual path is http://jamiserver.com/cokehi, where cokehi is my application. I use Url.Content("~/Content/img/header.png") expecting that this resource will be searched in /cokehi directory, but as a matter of fact it's being searched in root web site. I'm getting 404 error: can't found http://jamiserver.com/Content/img/header.png. Actually, "header.png" is located at http://jamiserver.com/cokehi/Content/img/header.png.
How to solve it? Thanks.

**EDITED:** Here is a screenshot to make sure that it's been run as a web application.
[image]

Comment: It sounds like cokehi isn't actually configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Check out screenshot I've added to question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running it as an Application, not a Virtual Directory

Comment: Please check out the edit of the question. I've added a screenshot.